# Проблема с mysql. Max allowed packet

Tags: java, mysql, ubuntu

Здравствуйте. Не могу подключиться к mysql серверу, пишет что max_allowed_packet очень маленький и нужно редактировать это поле на сервере. Меняю это на сервере с помощью запроса

```
set global max_allowed_packet = 434558800;
```

Получаю результат "Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning"
Как можно посмотреть это предупреждение ?

После чего перезагружаю Mysql, ничего не меняется. Также писал в файлах my.cnf, my.ini

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 434558800
```

Перезагружал и сервер, ничего не помогает.

Comment: Какая версия MySQL установлена ?

Comment: версия mysql 5.7.18

Comment: `[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 50M` поставь так.Предел протокола для max_allowed_packet составляет 1 ГБ

Comment: Это не помогло мне решить проблему.

Comment: `max_allowed_packet = 500M ` поиграй с этими цифрами.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet

Comment: Дело в том, что оно не обновляет.

Comment: Когда вы изменяете размер буфера сообщения, изменяя значение переменной max_allowed_packet, вы также должны изменить размер буфера на стороне клиента, если ваша клиентская программа разрешает это. Значение max_allowed_packet по умолчанию, встроенное в клиентскую библиотеку, составляет 1 ГБ, но отдельные клиентские программы могут отменить это. Например, mysql и mysqldump имеют значения по умолчанию 16 МБ и 24 МБ соответственно. Они также позволяют изменять значение на стороне клиента, устанавливая max_allowed_packet в командной строке или в файле параметров.

Comment: У меня там стоит 10 мб. Я меняю на 50. Запросом, который я выше описал. Перезагружаю, делаю запрос для просмотра переменной, значение не меняется.

Comment: И чо , тоже самое ?

Comment: Вы должны увеличить это значение, если используете большие столбцы BLOB или длинные строки. Он должен быть больше самого большого BLOB, который вы хотите использовать.

Comment: Сервер как будто мне не дает менять это значение и я не знаю, что делать.

Comment: Запрос при всём желании не может изменить значения, записанного в конфигурационном файле сервера. Соответственно при рестарте сервера будет взято значение из файла - т.е. установка благополучно потеряется. Но до рестарта будет действовать установленное запросом значение. Так что откорректируйте файл конфигурации и перезапустите MySQL-сервер

Comment: Нашел решение. Просто менял немного не тот файл. Спасибо всем.

Comment: *Как можно посмотреть это предупреждение ?* - `SHOW WARNINGS`